# Software to change size of a window in Windows XP SP 3

Tags: windows-xp, window

I am using Windows XP SP 3.

I need a software to quickly change the size(to 800x600, 1024x768 etc) of a window(not my monitor's resolution). Anybody heard such an application? When I google the same, all the links lists softwares that changes the monitor's resolution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the window's resolution?  Monitors have a resolution, windows have a size.

Comment: I did edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Sizer**](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/) might be just what you are looking for.

> Sizer is a freeware utility that allows you to resize any window to an
>   exact, predefined size.

[image]

I don't like recommending things I haven't tried so I just installed it and it works really well.  Simply right-click the border of the window you want to resize, like in the screenshot below and it gives you a list of sizes.  You can change the list from the main application.